# What's the right way to access logs for my user

Tags: server, permissions, ssh

I have vps for personal goals. Vps running on ubuntu 16.04 x64.

I'm config ssh to login only by my one user (schumi) by public key (login by password and login by root are disabled). If I needed change any config or install package, I'm did: `su -` and login by root with password.

But sometimes I want to see logs (/var/log) and ofcouse can not did it:

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 root                syslog              .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root                root                ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root                root                alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root                root                apt
-rw-r-----  1 syslog              adm                 auth.log
-rw-------  1 root                utmp                btmp
-rw-r-----  1 root                adm                 dmesg
-rw-r--r--  1 root                root                dpkg.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root                root                faillog
-rw-r--r--  1 root                root                fontconfig.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root                root                fsck
-rw-rw-r--  1 root                utmp                lastlog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog              adm                 mail.err
-rw-r-----  1 syslog              adm                 mail.log
drwxr-xr-x  2 root                root                proftpd
-rw-r-----  1 syslog              adm                 syslog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog              adm                 syslog.1
drwxrwxr-x  2 debian-transmission debian-transmission transmission
-rw-rw-r--  1 root                utmp                wtmp
```

What's I do now? I login by ssh (schumi), then `su -` and see logs.
But may be better add my user (schumi) to some groups? Or it's not secure?

Also, I have thoughts to view logs without login by ssh.
For example, run telegram-bot on vps, enable conversation bot only with me and implements commands to send log files to me by specific commands.
Or run, for example, nginx, config authentication and direct open log at web page...

Comment: The user created during setup in Ubuntu is added to the `adm` group by default, allowing them to view most of those logs (syslog, dmesg, auth.log, ...). Complain to your VPS if they didn't add your user to `adm`.

Comment: I can not install manual ubuntu. I can only choose OS for my server, then I getting root password. After that I add user (schumi) to system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the user yourself, add it to the `adm` group:

```
sudo adduser schumi adm
```

This will let the user read most of those logs.